# Material-Ui - CardMedia : LazyImage with Skeleton and inferring dimensions

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui, responsive-design

I would like to build a component CardEntry in a flexbox context.
Inside this component, I have a [CardMedia](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/card-media/) with a child named LazyImage.
LazyImage has a [Skeleton](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-skeleton/) when image is loading.
The guidelines I would like to have for LazyImage :

1. It should be "smart" (not to provide parent height / width, ...) to render the image as I use also srcset, with different width / height, ...
2. It works in a flex context
3. Use as much possible [React.lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy)

My code for the moment :

LazyImage :

```
    import { useState, useRef } from "react";
    import type { ImgHTMLAttributes, CSSProperties } from "react";
    
    import Skeleton from '@mui/material/Skeleton';
    // TODO Probably same styles that Skeleton
    import BrokenImageIcon from '@mui/icons-material/BrokenImage';
    
    // @ts-ignore
    import { useIntersection } from "../../hooks/useIntersection.tsx";
    
    // Type props
    interface PropsLazyImage {
        // Link for src 
        imagePath: string,
        // alt for image
        title: string,
        // Props for images
        propsImage?: ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>
    }
    
    type loadingStatus = 'loading' | 'error' | 'loaded';
    
    function LazyImage(props : PropsLazyImage) {
    
        const [ isInView, setIsInView ] = useState(false);
        const [ imageStatus, setImageStatus ] = useState("loading" as loadingStatus);
        const { imagePath, title, propsImage = {}} = props;
    
        const imgRef = useRef();
        useIntersection(imgRef, () => {
            setIsInView(true);
        });
        // CSSProperties
    
        return <div
            ref={imgRef as any}
            className="image-container"
        >
            { (imageStatus === "error") && <BrokenImageIcon />}
            { !isInView && (imageStatus === "loading") && <Skeleton variant="rectangular"/> }
            { isInView && (
                <img
                    src={imagePath}
                    alt={title}
                    onError={() => setImageStatus("error")}
                    onLoad={() => setImageStatus("loaded")}
                    style={{
                        objectFit: 'inherit',
                        position: 'absolute',
                        height: "inherit",
                        top: "0px"
                    }}
                    // Extra image attributes
                    {...propsImage}
                />
            )}
        </div>
    }
    
    export default LazyImage;
```

Hook useIntersection :

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import type { RefObject } from "react";

let listenerCallbacks = new WeakMap();

let observer;

function handleIntersections(entries) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (listenerCallbacks.has(entry.target)) {
      let cb = listenerCallbacks.get(entry.target);

      if (entry.isIntersecting || entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
        observer.unobserve(entry.target);
        listenerCallbacks.delete(entry.target);
        cb();
      }
    }
  });
}

function getIntersectionObserver(options : IntersectionObserverInit) {
  if (observer === undefined) {
    observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersections, options);
  }
  return observer;
}

export function useIntersection(
  elem : RefObject<any>, 
  callback, 
  options = {
    rootMargin: '100px',
    threshold: 0.15,
  } as IntersectionObserverInit
) {
  useEffect(() => {
    let target = elem.current;
    let observer = getIntersectionObserver(options);
    listenerCallbacks.set(target, callback);
    observer.observe(target);

    return () => {
      listenerCallbacks.delete(target);
      observer.unobserve(target);
    };
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
}
```

CardEntry

```
import { Suspense, useState, lazy } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

// To check what should happen when clicking on a game
import { useTheme, styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import useMediaQuery from '@mui/material/useMediaQuery';

import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import CardMedia from "@mui/material/CardMedia";
import CardActionArea from '@mui/material/CardActionArea';

// @ts-ignore
import LazyImage from "../Others/LazyImage.tsx";

// @ts-ignore
const CardDialog = lazy(() => import("./CardDialog.tsx"));

const PREFIX = 'CardEntry';

const classes = {
    gameRoot: `${PREFIX}-gameRoot`,
    gameCover: `${PREFIX}-gameCover`,
    MuiCardActionArea: `${PREFIX}-MuiCardActionArea`
};

const StyledCard = styled(Card)((
    {
        theme
    }
) => ({
    [`&.${classes.gameRoot}`]: {
        position: "relative",
        //height: "100%"
    },
    [`& .${classes.gameCover}`]: {
        zIndex: 1,
        //height: "inherit"
    },
    [`& .${classes.MuiCardActionArea}`]: {
        height: "inherit",
        zIndex: 1
    }
}));

// for responsive pictures
const PICTURE_SIZES = ["small", "medium", "big"];
const SIZES_WITDH = {
    "small": "150w",
    "medium": "200w",
    "big": "250w"
}

function CardEntry(props) {

    // hooks
    const theme = useTheme();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    // props
    const {game} = props;

    const is_mobile_device = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('md'));

    // state of context menu
    const [contextMenuOpen,setContextMenuOpen] = useState(false);
    
    // consts
    const {
        title: gameTitle,
        url: gameURL
    } = game;
    const local_path = game.url_type === "PLAYLIST" ? "/playlist/" + game.playlistId : "/video/" + game.videoId;

    function watchGame() {
        if (is_mobile_device) {
            window.location.href = gameURL;
        } else {
            navigate(local_path);
        }
    }

    // image properties
    let imageProps : {
        srcSet?: string
    } = {};

    // only 
    if (game?.hasResponsiveImages) {
        // TODO maybe in the future make that stuff more configurable
        imageProps.srcSet= PICTURE_SIZES
            .map(size=>`${game.imagesFolder}/cover@${size}.webp ${SIZES_WITDH[size]}`)
            .join(",");
    }

    return (
        <StyledCard className={classes.gameRoot}>

            <CardActionArea 
                onClick={watchGame}
                onContextMenu={(event) => {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    setContextMenuOpen(true);
                }}
                classes={{root: classes.MuiCardActionArea}}
            >
                <CardMedia
                    className={classes.gameCover}
                    title={gameTitle}
                >
                    <LazyImage 
                        imagePath={game.imagePath}
                        title={gameTitle}
                        propsImage={imageProps}
                    />
                </CardMedia>

            </CardActionArea>
            <Suspense fallback={null}>
                <CardDialog game={game} contextMenuState={[contextMenuOpen,setContextMenuOpen]} />
            </Suspense>
        </StyledCard>
    );
}

export default CardEntry;
```

Example of HOC component that invokes CardEntry

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";

// Custom
// @ts-ignore
import ReloadWrapper from "../Others/ReloadWrapper.tsx";

// @ts-ignore
import CardEntry from "../GamesView/CardEntry.tsx";

// Redux
// @ts-ignore
import { fetchLatestVideos } from "../../services/latestVideosSlice.tsx";
// @ts-ignore
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from '../Store.tsx';

const PREFIX = 'LatestVideosGallery';

const classes = {
    gameEntry: `${PREFIX}-gameEntry`,
    gamesCriteria: `${PREFIX}-gamesCriteria`
};

const StyledLatestVideosGallery = styled('div')((
    {
        theme
    }
) => ({
    [`& .${classes.gameEntry}`]: {
        [theme.breakpoints.only('xs')]: {
            flexBasis: "calc((100% / 1) - 1%)"
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.only('sm')]: {
            flexBasis: "calc((100% / 2) - 1%)"
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.only('md')]: {
            flexBasis: "calc((100% / 4) - 1%)"
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
            flexBasis: "calc((100% / 5) - 1%)"
        },
    },
    [`& .${classes.gamesCriteria}`]: {
        display: "flex",
        [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
            flexDirection: "column",
            rowGap: "8px"
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
            flexDirection: "row",
            justifyContent: "flex-end"
        }
    }
}));

// The gallery component
function LatestVideosGallery(props) {

    const dispatch: AppDispatch = useDispatch();
    const loading = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.latestVideos.loading);
    const error = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.latestVideos.error);
    const data = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.latestVideos.items);

    // on mount, load data (only once)
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchLatestVideos());
    }, 
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
        []
    );

    return (
        <ReloadWrapper 
            loading={loading}
            error={error}
            reloadFct={() => {dispatch(fetchLatestVideos());}}
            component={
                <StyledLatestVideosGallery>    
                    <Grid
                        container
                        spacing={1}
                        style={
                            {
                                rowGap: "15px"
                            }
                        }
                    >
                        {
                            data
                                .map(game => 
                                        <Grid 
                                            key={game.videoId} 
                                            item 
                                            className={classes.gameEntry}
                                        >
                                            <CardEntry game={game}/>
                                        </Grid>
                                )
                        }
                    </Grid>
                </StyledLatestVideosGallery>            
            }
        />
    );
}

export default LatestVideosGallery;
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: As it demo : https://jy95.github.io/games